# Is there a way to use google account to fill forms?

Tags: forms, google-account

I've got some landing pages with forms/newsletter signups. Is it possible to use google accounts to autofill the forms? Example:

1. I've got a form that asks for name, email, phone, etc.
2. The user see's the form and clicks on a button like "fill with
   google account details"
3. The form gets filled and send

Making the process a bit easier and quicker for the user than having to type in all the details.